# Spring, Angular JS e tratamento de exceção na camada de Serviço

Tags: angularjs, json, exceção, spring-mvc, java-ee-7

Tenho uma aplicação que usa [jasper-reports](/questions/tagged/jasper-reports) versão 6.2.0 com [spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc) versão 3.2.14, [java-ee-7](/questions/tagged/java-ee-7), [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat) 8 e no front-end utilizamos [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs). As requisições [rest](/questions/tagged/rest) são feitas via [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax).

A aplicação está toda pronta para receber objetos [json](/questions/tagged/json) como retorno das requisições, pois as requisições via [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) são todas feitas via Ajax. Em determinada funcionalidade da aplicação temos uma requisição "comum" utilizando `window.location = url`, pois precisamos retornar um streaming que nada mais é que um array de bytes para gerar um arquivo PDF.

Com isso, quando existe algum erro no back-end a resposta vai para uma tela em branco com um objeto [json](/questions/tagged/json) impresso na mesma.

Já utilizei tratamento de erros com [spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc) global ou por exceção, seja utilizando tratamento por anotações com [ExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) ou com [ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) para generalizar, porém sempre tratando classes na camada de controle com anotação [Controller](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/Controller.html) retornando um objeto [ModelAndView](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html), mas nunca classes na camada de serviço anotadas com [Service](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html).

Minha dúvida seria como ao capturar a exceção fazer com que o [spring-mvc](/questions/tagged/spring-mvc) redirecionasse para uma tela de erro nos meus casos de requisições via Get comum com uma mensagem parametrizada neste cenário que descrevi.

Answer (score 2):

Obtenha o conteúdo binário do arquivo no caso de sucesso. Para isso, utilize o serviço `$http` em conjunto com [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob):

```
$http({
    url: 'site/endPointQueRetornaConteudoBinario',
    method: "POST",
    data: json, //caso você precise mandar algum conteúdo no POST body
    headers: {
       'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    // O resultado é válido:
    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/pdf"});
    var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(objectUrl);
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    //Falhou: Faça seu handler aqui.
});
```

[Fonte.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447952/angularjs-http-post-convert-binary-to-excel-file-and-download)

Comment: Você poderia explicar um pouco mais o que faz o método createObjectURL(blob)?